# Не могу придумать абстракцию для класса

Tags: c++

Задание у меня следующее. Есть класс часы и в нем содержится статическое поле "часовой пояс". Необходимо перевести все часы, когда изменяется статическое поле. Помогите придумать абстракцию (по проще) - какие поля придумать, какие методы должны быть и каким образом реализовать эти часы, ибо в голову совершенно ничего не лезет.

Comment: Храни время в UTC формате и при выводе используй сдвиг текущего часового пояса. Все доволи тривиально ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1.

У поля `часовой пояс` есть событие onChange. На это событие подписываются все экземпляры класса `часы` и при его возникновении проводят корректировку времени.

Вариант 2.

Класса `часы` хранит время в формате, независимом от часового пояса. А при запросе и установке времени делает поправку с учетом значения поля `часовой пояс`.

Например

```
class Clock {
  public:
    static int TZOfset;
  private:
    int Seconds;
  public:
    int getSeconds() {
      return Seconds + TZOffset * 3600;
    }
    void setSeconds(int val) {
      Seconds = val - TZOffset * 3600;
    }
}
```

Comment: а можете более подробно объяснить второй вариант?

Comment: @Trapezant Добавил код

Comment: а каким образом перевести все созданные часы?

Comment: @Trapezant Этого не нужно делать. При последующие запросы времени для отображения дадут скорректированные значения

Comment: не совсем вас понял